# upload file question

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am wondering if the data posted to the server is same when using

1) ASP.Net upload file control
2) Webclient.UploadFile method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is absolutely the same respecting the [RFC 2388](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2388.html) (`multipart/form-data`). This being said I wouldn't recommend you using ASP.Net upload file control in an ASP.NET MVC application.

Comment: Can you say why? I was under the impression that any ASP.NET controls were safe to use in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: None of the web controls are *safe* to be used in an ASP.NET MVC application because they rely on ViewState and the Postback model, notions that no longer exist in MVC.